# Which kind of service should I implement for a continuous background task?

Tags: android, android-service

I've been checking google's documentation for some days but I'm not sure how should I do this.

The idea over my head, is to create a service which runs in background (forever) even if device restarts, etc. (like for example, WhatsApp). This service should go over the internet every 30 minutes just on Thursdays (for example).

However, I'm not sure if I've to create a classic Service, one with a BroadCastReceiver, etc.

I want some explanations about where to focus my search. **Which kind of service should I use to perform a never ending task?**

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Im asking what should I search for to accomplish my requirements. I'm not looking for code help, just some tips about what should I search, as I find many information about 2-3 kinds of service but I'm not able to fit any of them on my requirements.

Comment: Please read up on Android OS, app running in the background should be avoided at all times!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one wants an app that runs forever in the background. You want an app that is periodically launched (in background), does it thing, and sleeps again.

Also, in android nothing will ever run 'forever'. The lifetime is handled by Android OS, meaning if it wants resources it can kill your app.

So you could two things:

- `BroadcastReceiver` + `Service`: the BR listens to the Android Booted `Intent`, then starts your Service which may run indefinitely (using `startService`).
- `AlarmManager` + `BroadcastReceiver` (+ `Service`): create alarms at specified intervals your want your BR launched. The BR can then start the `Service` which does the heavy work. After the Service is done it should kill himself!

`IntentService` cannot be used, because it will kill himself when there are no more tasks
`BroadcastReceived` cannot be used alone, because it can only live for a couple of seconds (10sec)

**tl;dr**

Don't make a Service which runs forever. Create a `Service` does it's task and kill himself when done. Then launch this `Service` periodically.

Comment: I think that the second option is going to be the best in my case. Thank you.